# MySQL Select Latest for multiple values

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

I have this database and want to query the latest dates for **only** the ID's 5,10,15,20. The result of this query should be only the first four rows of that database. 
How would I do that?

Comment: It's always appreciated if you show some effort by posting the SQL you have attempted.

Comment: You already put `group by` as a tag. In addition you need `max()` and you are done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use in and group by

```
 select * 
 from my_table 
 where (date, myID) in (select max(date), myID 
                       from my_table 
                       where myID in  (5,10,15,20)
                       group by myID );
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a correlated subquery to find the max dates for the listed id's. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery

```
`SELECT * 
FROM Foo f1
WHERE f1.Date = (
                 SELECT MAX(Date)
                 FROM Foo f2
                 WHERE f1.Id = f2.Id
                )
AND f1.Id IN (5,10,15,20);`
```

Without having your exact table structure locally, I can't verify the syntax, but this is the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

Not an optimal solution, but its working :

```
select myid, mydate from myTable where myid in (5,10,15,20) order By mydate DSC limit 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's just the ID and the corresponding date you need, the following should suffice:

```
SELECT
   mt.myID,
   MAX(mt.date) AS latestDate
FROM myTable mt
WHERE mt.myID IN (5, 10, 15, 20)
GROUP BY myID
```